# How do I import special.elliprj and special.elliprf from SciPy?

Tags: python, scipy

I have an issue importing the scipy.special package.
More precisely when I import elliprf and elliprj, because with ellipk and ellipe I have no problems using it.
With elliprf and elliprj I get the following message:

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy.special' has no attribute 'elliprj'
```

I have tried using special.elliprj and elliprj. The way I import is as follows:

```
from scipy import special
```

Comment: [`elliprj`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.elliprj.html) was added to SciPy in version 1.8.0.  Which version do you have installed?  If you don't know, you can check by running `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: @Warren I have the 1.6.2 Scipy, How can I upgrade the version?

Comment: This will upgrade scipy to the last version 1.8.1: `pip install -U scipy`